# Best Practice for shared state between blocs in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am new to bloc and I found that *whenever I am creating a new page with it's own bloc, I have to create a **Loading state** and **ShowLoading event** repeatedly.* What is the best practice to avoid this? I have tried multiple ways such as BaseBloc and BaseState, which allows others bloc to inherit it but none of them work. Is there any implementation or boiler plate for this? Thank you.

Comment: This is something that I believe Bloc needs to address. There are so many different Blocs that share the same state, like a Loading State, a generic Success state, a Failure state. Pretty much every time I use a bloc I'm writing a Loading state. A Base bloc would be nice

Answer (score 1):

when you wat to use BaseBloc  you will end up with writing with a code  that is not nicely written and you can not use it in the root of the widget tree.

the Bloc way from what I notice is that each bloc is related to a Page/feature and each one will have it's own loading state  and that Page will respond to it's loading state, you can notice that in the documentation page under [Naming Conventions](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/blocnamingconventions?id=naming-conventions)

to run around that issue usually I would go to make my loading widget inside a snack bar with loader inside it, and call it  each time there is a  loading state. that will make it easy to change it in the future from one place or maybe you can search for some library that can do the loading for you each time you call some method from the blocs.

another idea is to wrap the root widget with a provider that will trigger a loading widget on the root top of the widget each time you call some provider method(like `showLoader()` ), and from inside the bloc/blocs you can call the provider method that will trigger the loading each time from anywhere, maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-make-multiple-global-loaders-in-flutter-348fd76d449) is helpful for that  .